# Which is the best way to display images in Android?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

so im developing an app that shows a lot of images to the user. The problem im facing is that currently for the prototype,ive stored my images in the drawable folder. But this seems to slow the app down loading images and usually gives a OutofMemory error. so after some searching iv figured out that i can

1) Load them from a sqlite Databse or

2) download them from a server/cloud on the first run of the app and use them from a particular directory

which one of these would be the most appropriate and efficient as il be using images that are mostly above 1MB?

Comment: How many is "a lot of"?

Comment: @juan at the moment i have 11 images in my drawable folder.i plan to show at least 20-25 images

Comment: First, you must realise that file size has little relevance to how much memory is required which is (without code to do something else) width x height x 4 bytes.  So a 1024 x 1024 image takes 4 MB.  But a 1024 x 1024 PNG of an all white background will be a few K in file size.

Answer (score 0):

25 images of about 1MB are not a big amount of data for an APP.

The problem here is the weight of every individual image. In your case, I recommend you to store them in a SQLite database because what makes your phone slow is dealing with every single image, the time to load them.

If you store them in a server you will have to add your load time to your download time...

Dummy advise: make them smaller xD

I hope this would help you ;)

Comment: but i read that sqlite gives problems with image sizes above 1mb that is why i was searching for an alternate method. becasue most of my images are above 1.5MB. would loading them from a directory be faster otherwise?

Comment: I'm afraid that reading from a directory wouldn't be faster. One of my project consist on app that manages 3D models for augmented reality. When I load the models from my sdcard, the app get extremelly slow (I'm talking about 3-4 mb for small 3D models). You could try and make some tests if you want...

Anyway: if you want to ask about the choice of downloading from a server or loading from memory my answer is storing images locally.